# display parts of a page inside two iframes in two separate parts of a page

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe

is it possible to display parts of a page inside two separate iframes, where the changes i make in either one of those iframe, will reflect on the other one?

part.html

```
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|             |                                                                    |
|   part 1    |                                                                    |
|             |                                                                    |
+-------------+                                                                    |  
|                                                                                  |
|                                                                                  |  
+-------------+                                                                    |         |             |                                                                    |
|   part 2    |                                                                    |
|             |                                                                    |
+-------------+                                                                    |             |                                                                                  |
|                                                                                  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

frame 1 will load part 1 of part.html

frame 2 will load part 2 of part.html

main.html

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                  |
|                                                                                  |
|  +----------------+                                                              |
|  |                |                                                              |
|  |                |                                                              |
|  |     frame 1    |                                                              |
|  |                |                                                              |
|  |                |                                                              |
|  +----------------+                                                              |
|                                                                                  |
|                                                                                  |
|                                                        +---------------+         |
|                                                        |               |         |
|                                                        |               |         |
|                                                        |     frame 2   |         |
|                                                        |               |         |
|                                                        |               |         |
|                                                        +---------------+         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

i want the iframes to still function as one page, as if they are not loaded separately, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is possible bt not that easy, Can I asck you why would you want such approach?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this. First you can simple append a parameter in each page call (part.php?part=1 / part.php?part=2) and add some logic inside the part.php file that response with the appropriate content.

But I'm pretty sure that there are better ways to realize what you try to implement. First you should read this, and understand why there are better ways than using frames:

http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/website-frames/

http://www.free2code.net/tutorials/view/replace_frames_with_php_tables-27/page1.html

(The second example uses tables but you should put your focus on "include")

Then you should have a look at your structure and maybe find a solution to split up your "part.htm" file. One file for all content can become very unhandy.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use iframes, but script some sort of frame myself.

By using two divs as viewports, and having both texts embedded in a div with a shared class you can move them both up and down. The viewport then blocks the rest of the page.
Using jquery you can catch the scroll event, and then you should be able to move both pages up and down.
(The intent is now fired by clicking one of the the texts).

To give you an idea I have built you a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SGSDs/5/

**UPDATE:**
You can load your external page by using AJAX. This is a good tutorial: http://webhole.net/2009/06/13/ajax-page-loading-with-jquery/

HTML:

```
<div class="viewport"><div class="remotepage" id="part1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div></div>
<hr>
<div class="viewport"><div class="remotepage" id="part2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.viewport {
  width: 200px;  
  height: 200px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.remotepage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

#part2 {
    margin-top: -200px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {   
    $(document).on("click", ".remotepage", function() {
        $(".remotepage").animate({ top: "-=50px" }, 0);
    });
});
```